# Beginner: R custom plot function doesn't run all lines?? (Quantmod)

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

Basic question on trying to use a function to plot (using Quantmod).
Function runs the 'chartSeries function' **seems to skip the next lines** and runs the addBBands command (or whichever 'add'-command is last.

Have tried to use Sys.sleep() in there thinking it was due to r not having enough time to pull the graphic, but to no avail.

Any ideas welcome!

Code:

```
QuantPlot2019<-function(stockname){
  chartSeries(Stockname,subset='2019-01-01::2019-12-31',theme=chartTheme('white'))
    addEMA(n=30,col='magenta')
    addMACD(fast=12,slow=26,signal=9,type='EMA')
    addBBands(n=20,sd=2)
}

getSymbols("...")
Stockname<-...
QuantPlot2019()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the function below and see if it works:

```
 QuantPlot2019<-function(stockname){
    chartSeries(eval(parse(text=Stockname)),subset='2019-01-01::2019-12- 
                     31',theme=chartTheme('white'))
    addEMA(n=30,col='magenta')
    addMACD(fast=12,slow=26,signal=9,type='EMA')
    addBBands(n=20,sd=2)
}
```